# Why is my transistor is letting through current?

Tags: mosfet, basic

I'm working my way through the Arduino starter kit project book and am doing the first project involving a transistor (MOSFET). As far as I understand, what I've done is wired up a 9V battery, a resistor and LED, and the source/drain pins of the MOSFET in series. Since there's no voltage on the gate pin, I expect the LED to be dead, but it's shining. I'm not 100% sure which pin on the MOSFET is the gate (the book says it's the one I'm not using), but only this combination of pins produces light from the LED.

[Here](https://imgur.com/a/JT4mEYG) are some photos of my circuit, and here's what I *think* is happening diagrammatically:

[image]

Comment: You say gate, but your schematic shows a BJT which has a gate but a base. Which is it? This matters because the gate-source is a small capacitor, and capacitors retain voltage, and the gate-source voltage difference is what controls whether a MOSFET conducts or not. But this is not the case for a BJT.

Comment: Also, if you aren't sure which pin on your transistor is which then we can't really help you explain why it's lit up except to say that hooking up wrong two pins will allow current to flow.  BJTs and MOSFETs have inherent diodes across certain pins so, yeah, if you hook it up in that way it's going to allow current through as if it were a diode. Unlike a door you have encountered, just because a transistor is blocking current in one direction does not imply it will block current in the opposite direction.

Comment: [This](https://www.arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/MosfetTransistor.pdf) is the transistor - I can't figure out from the documentation which pin is which. Maybe I used the wrong symbol in the diagram - in any case, what I mean by that symbol is that I have the LED connected to one pin of the MOSFET and ground connected to another. According to the book that came with the kit, the two pins that cause the LED to light up are the source/drain pins, but maybe it's wrong or I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: The pin assignments are on Page 8. It lists it generally for MOSFETs and IGBTs. You have a MOSFET so use those assignments. And in a 99.9% of discrete MOSFET are constructed such that there is a diode between the source-drain. So hook it up the wrong way and current will flow uncontrolled.

Comment: @DKNguyen Oh, sorry, I saw that diagram but ignored it because at a glance it looked like a circuit diagram (my eyes read the arrows as wires). In any case, it looks like the pins I'm using are source and drain, and they're making the LED light up.

Comment: Then one of two things is happening: Either you have the source-drain backwards so the so-called body diode is conducting (99.9% of discrete MOSFETs are constructed with a body diode and so will block current in only one direction but conduct in two directions). The second is that you have connected it properly but you have introduced a charge into the gate-source capacitance. This is equivalent to applying a control voltage between the gate-source terminals which is keeping the MOSFET activated. This retained charge cannot drain because you have left the gate floating.

Comment: Though capacitor leakage will eventually drain it.

Comment: @DKNguyen 100% of MOSFETs, discrete or otherwise have a body diode; it's an integral part of the structure and can't be removed. It's not something that's added intentionally (unlike with IGBTs, which frequently do have an antiparallel diode added intentionally).

Comment: @Hearth Well, I guess the main interest is whether the diode is connected between the source-drain, which for discrete diodes it is.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ah, I'll give you that, then. That *is* true for only 99.99% of discrete FETs; there are a handful of parts with a separate body terminal.

Comment: *discrete MOSFETs, not diodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's multiple options.

First of all, the transistor drawn is not a FET but a BJT.

Either you have drain and source swapped, so current flows through the intrinsic body diode.

Or, the drain and source are the correct way around, and there is voltage on gate so transistor is on.

Having a gate disconnected does not mean there is no voltage.

It is possible that leakage current or you touching the gate with fingers has caused charge to flow to gate and accumumate voltage.

Or, the FET is damaged by ESD.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess blowing the MOSFET is the third possibility. Semiconductors tend to fail short.

Comment: Yes, I had drain and source mixed up! I didn't realize that would allow current to flow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet has answers for you:

[image: Mosfet]

Comment: That datasheet has surprisingly inconsistent terminal designations. The IRF520 is no GEMFET. FWIW, it's not the datasheet [hyperlinked by Jack M](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666576/why-is-my-transistor-is-letting-through-current/666578#comment1774316_666576).

Comment: That image lists "collector" and "emitter" terminals, yet this is a MOSFET, not a BJT or IGBT. Whatever datasheet you're looking at, I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: Jack posted the International Rectifier Mosfet datasheet as a comment. They must hire school kids to do their datasheets.